# Use WatiN for automation upload file on the website

Tags: upload, file-upload, dialog, watin

I need upload file on the website.
But Have a problem, i can't choose file automatic in code. Always browser show me choose file window.
What wrong in my code?

```
IE ie = new IE("https://www.xxxx.com/WFrmlogin.aspx");
FileUploadDialogHandler uploadHandler = new FileUploadDialogHandler(@"D:\065-6405_URGENT.xls");

ie.WaitForComplete();
ie.TextField(Find.ById("txtUser")).TypeText("login");
ie.TextField(Find.ById("txtPassWord")).TypeText("***");

ie.Button(Find.ById("btnok")).Click();
ie.WaitForComplete();


ie.GoTo("https://www.orientspareparts.com/inq/WFrmUpOption.aspx");
ie.WaitForComplete();

ie.DialogWatcher.Clear();
ie.AddDialogHandler(uploadHandler);
// This code show choose file dialog
ie.FileUpload(Find.ById("FilUpload")).ClickNoWait();


ie.Button(Find.ById("butUpload")).Click();
ie.WaitForComplete();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to select from the Dialog? Try to just set the Text:

```
ie.FileUpload(Find.ById("profile_file")).Text = "C:/Desktop/image.jpg";
```

I guess you might talk to the fellow who asked this question:
[WatiN File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065611/watin-file-upload/3409802#3409802)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I'm using a GMail-like upload process, so I wanted to test actual use-cases.  Just setting the Text property on my hidden file input wasn't an option.

I ended up using SendKeys to type the path to my file, then sent "{ENTER}" to submit the dialog.

```
SetForegroundWindow(browser.hWnd);
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
Thread.Sleep(500); // An unfortunate necessity, to give the dialog time to pop up.
SendKeys.SendWait(@"C:\myfile.jpg{ENTER}")
```

I don't love this solution, especially not the sleep, but it was the best I could do in under 30 mins.

If anyone has a better option, let me know!